# data successfully sent via form post but not through jquery serialize or formdata class

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

there is a form that seems to be successfully posted if sent as a normal formpost (page redirect) .

but if the same is sent via jquery serialize or FormData object , it sends an empty object ..

sample form and ajax call is as under:

```
 <form role="form" action="@Url.Action("InsertUpdateQuestion", "TemplateBuilder")" method="post" id="questionTempDetailsForm" >
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-xs-4">
                                        <label class="control-label small" for="ShortName">Short Name<span class="required">*</span></label>
                                        <input class="form-control" id="ShortName" name="ShortName" type="text">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-4">
                                        <label class="control-label small" for="questionType">Type<span class="required">*</span></label>
                                        @Html.DropDownList("QuestionTypeId", (List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.QuestionType, "-- Select --",
                                       new { @id = "questionType", @name = "questionType", @class = "chosen-select form-control", onchange = @"QuestionTypeChanged(this.value);" })
                                        <input id="questionTypeName" name="questionTypeName" type="text" hidden="hidden">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-2 pad-a-labelsize">
                                        <div class="checkbox-custom checkbox-default">
                                            <input id="chkNewLine" style="margin-top: 20px;" name="chkNewLine" type="checkbox">
                                            <h5 class="modal-title small">New Line</h5>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-2 pad-a-labelsize-btn">
                                        <button id="btnQuestionSave" style="margin-top: 23px;" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm rightbtn " type="button" onclick="SubmitQuestionData();"> Save</button>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                                        <label class="control-label small" for="questionName">Question<span class="required">*</span></label>
                                        <input class="form-control" id="questionName" name="questionName" type="text" placeholder="Your Question" onblur="getText();">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
</form>
```

ajax call:

```
function SubmitQuestionData() {
        debugger;
        //return true;
        var myform = document.getElementById("questionTempDetailsForm");
        var fd = new FormData(myform);

        var url = $("#questionTempDetailsForm").attr("action");


        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "post",
            data: fd,
            dataType: "json",
            async: false,
            traditional: true,
            processData: false,
            success: function (msg) {
                ShowAlertMessage(msg.ResponseText, msg.MessageClass);
                if (msg.RedirectUrl != null && msg.RedirectUrl.length > 0) {
                    setTimeout(LoadPage, 1500, msg.RedirectUrl, "User");

                }
            },
            error: function (res) {
                ShowAlertMessage("an error occured..", "User");
            }
        });

        return false;
    }
```

any help highly appreciated..

Comment: 1) You're sending binary FormData in your AJAX request, whereas the HTML form is sending form-urlencoded data. This means this is likely a problem with how the server is expecting to receive the data. Try just using sending the data from your form using `serialize()` instead 2) Remove `async: false`. It's incredibly bad practice. 3) I'd suggest using an unobtrusive event handler instead of an outdated `on*` event attribute. Preferably attaching to the `submit` event of the form in this case, instead of the click of your submit button.

Comment: thank you for the comment, can you kindly guide how we can differentiate between binary/normal form data in ajax

Comment: Just change this line: `var fd = $('#questionTempDetailsForm').serialize()`

Comment: that also seem to return an empty string :)

Comment: What response are you expecting?

Comment: response is a json .. 
but currently stuck at posting data .. response is the next thing